# How to convert the date format 'MM/DD/YY' to 'DD-MM(in words)-YYYY' like (13-SEC-2013)

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am getting one data filed from one text file at format 'MM/DD/YY'(like '08/13/13'). Now I want to convert it as 'DD-MM(in words)-YYYY' like (13-SEC-2013).

Please help me in this conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this function.

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DATE,'MM-DD-YY'),'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Or

```
       v_PORT(DateTime)-TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(INPUTPORT),'MM/DD/YY')
       o_PORT(String)--TO_CHAR(v_PORT,'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Both it's working and coming like this.(13-SEC-2013)

Comment: please don't add any greetings nor contact data to your answers (thought you might get the hint by my recent edits ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Convert input value to date by using to_char(to_date(in_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'DD-MON-YYYY')

Credit: [Change Date Format](http://www.queryhome.com/48001/how-to-convert-the-date-format-mm-dd-yy-to-dd-mmm-yyyy)

Answer (score 0):

V_PORT=**TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(INPUT_PORT,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'DD/MM/YYYY')**

NOTE:- IF input port data is in timestamp then you have to use substr function to get only the date.
you can use like **SUBSTR(INPUT_PORT,1,10)**

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others

Answer (score 0):

All close

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(I_DATE,'MM/DD/YY'),'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21632361)

Comment: While I tried to modify the posts of others (along with critique). They were rejected thus posted my own. Ultimately the approaches suggested were sound but the other posts didn't pay attention to the incoming format of the date provided by the original poster (easy mistake to make more typo than anything)

Answer (score -1):

Try this it will work

```
IIF(ISNULL(HIREDATE),TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM-DD-YY'),'DD-MON-YYYY'),HIREDATE)
```